# How to set a dynamic gitlab job tag with a variable?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a dynamic job that can switch between two gitlab runners depending on which tag it is given.  I would like to do this with an environmental variable, but it seems this cannot be used.  The following job:

```
runner_test:
  image: alpine
  tags:
    - $MY_RUNNER
  stage: deploy_main
  script:
    - echo foobar
  retry: 2
```

Results in a paused pipeline with the error: `This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online or available with any of these tags assigned to them: $MY_RUNNER`

Comment: How is your `$MY_RUNNER` CI variable value defined?  There's no `variables:` definition block in your example yaml, and your question doesn't state that you're passing the value in some other way.   The error seems to indicate that it doesn't have a value, so it's being interpreted as a literal string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is currently not available. There is currently an open issue which is in the backlog requesting this feature: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1809.

---

A work around perhaps, using [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) and [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends):

```
.template:
  stage: deploy_main
  script:
    - echo foobar

runner_test_1:
  extends: .template
  tags:
    - runner_1
  rules:
    - if: $RUNNER_TAG == runner_1
    
runner_test_2:
  extends: .template
  tags:
    - runner_2
  rules:
    - if: $RUNNER_TAG == runner_2
```

or something to that effect.

Comment: It's unfortunate dynamic tags not a feature yet. Yes, I wound up doing something similar using only/except to allow dynamic job selection. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced

Comment: Anyone has an update on this one - seems a while back, issue is closed, but no proper solution is mentioned anywhere?

Comment: @Iony I've updated the link to the issue, supposedly being released this month.

Comment: Hi Guys, any updates on this issue. It seems we are also stuck because of this.

Comment: There is a new feature in 14.4 called "Nested variable expansion" which can provide exactly what you want for dynamic runner tags. See documenation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#nested-variable-expansion

Comment: Oh this is just ridiculous, we have to triple our job numbers because of this.. Thank you for the work around but how silly...Not everyone has the luxury of being on the latest self-managed version.

Answer (score 15):

Dynamic job tags is achievable now (originally tested on 14.10, updated & tested on 16.2).  Variable interpolation works for job tags, however, an un-documented limitation is that variable changes within the job's YAML won't apply (even though the rules: keywords are supposed to be interpreted before anything else.)  This means that we need to set dynamic runner tags at the global level with the [workflow:rules:variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrulesvariables) key.

The following example would result in a default job tag of "staging" for most branches, and an override value of "production" for pipelines running against the project's default branch.

```yaml
# global pipeline variable for the default value
variables:
  RUNNER_TAG: "staging"  # default CI variable value

# global workflow:rules:variables can change variables outside of jobs
workflow:
  rules:
    # if the pipeline is on the default branch, then change the RUNNER_TAG variable
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      variables:
        RUNNER_TAG: "production"
    # ensure pipeline still runs if above conditions are not met
    - when: always 

# ci job using the dynamic runner tag
job:
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG
  script:
    - hello world from runner matching $RUNNER_TAG
```

NOTE: [workflow:rules:variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrulesvariables) was added in version 13.11 via a feature flag, and made available without a feature flag in version 14.1

Comment: This doesn't work, yes, the script echos the correct variable, but it always runs on the runner matching the staging tag (tested on 15.5)

Comment: Interesting, seems to be either a regression defect at some point or an undocumented limitation with variable interpolation on `tags:`   Either way, I've updated the example to use `workflow:rules:variables` instead, which _does_ work to change the job's runner tag value (tested on v16.2).  Thanks for the heads up, @UlfLindback

Comment: yes that works (test on gitlab runner 15.8.3), unfortunately you cannot set the RUNNER_TAG to a variable in the workflow (e.g. $OVERRIDE_RUNNER_TAG), but if you know the possible tags to allow, you can solve it with a number of if statements...

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/385676 tracks the limitation on setting the tag variable from a job rule.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is not possible on older versions of Gitlab, as a work around for those on older verisons of Gitlab, to extend on the answer given by Rekovni, if you're looking to run environment specific runners:

```
.Deploy_template:
  stage: Deploy
  image:
    name: busybox/busybox:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  rules:
    - when: manual
  before_script:
    - echo "Preflight tests"
  script:
    - echo "Start Deployment"
  after_script:
    - echo "Postflight tests"
  allow_failure: false


Deploy_feature:
  extends: .Deploy_template
  tags:
    - docker
    - feature
  rules:
    - if: $BRANCH =~ /feature/

Deploy_develop:
  extends: .Deploy_template
  tags:
    - docker
    - develop
  rules:
    - if: $BRANCH =~ /develop/

Deploy_stable:
  extends: .Deploy_template
  tags:
    - docker
    - stable
  rules:
    - if: $BRANCH =~ /stable/
```

Then you just repeat this for every job you have.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a large number of official issues, I finally found an indirect solution. Referenced from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35742#note_753691320

```
# contents of .gitlab-ci.yml
variables:
  TAG_VAR: runner-$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME-x86

stages:
  - build

build-job:
  stage: build
  trigger:
    include: .gitlab-ci-child.yml



# contents of .gitlab-ci-child.yml
stages:
  - build

workflow:
  rules:
    - when: always

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - $TAG_VAR
  script:
    - echo "Runner: $TAG_VAR"
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I have control of the repo branching structure, I make the CI branch names match the tags (e.g. dev, test, preprod, prod, etc). Then I can do something like this. However, this solution is not very portable for cases where you need to map the branch name to some other tag.

```yaml
tags:
  - ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
```

I really don't like the template, extends paradigm. It makes so much extra code. There must be a better way. There is [this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65850715/how-to-set-a-dynamic-gitlab-job-tag-with-a-variable) which is almost there. However, I cannot figure out how to make the source variable dynamically derived from another variable. Maybe it meets some people's use cases.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31741909)