# How to deploy to different enviroments based on workflow variables?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline

I found the [following proposal](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/209864) and tested it out (see code sample), but could not make it work.

We run on Gitlab 14.3.4, how can I determine if this is available for this version? If this feature is not working, how can I deploy to different environments if I have different runners one for my prod one for dev environment? So far, I have one pipeline for each environment using its dedicated tags - as dynamic tags are [not available so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65850715/how-to-set-a-dynamic-gitlab-job-tag-with-a-variable).

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "parent_pipeline"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS"
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature.*$/'
      variables:
        TARGET: dev
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confusing what is and isn't available (and I think that answer you linked is too). You can absolutely use variables to populate what runner your job should run with, I use it today in workflows on the SaaS offering.

Using variables to determine the runner tag can still be confusing though, because whether or not the variables works properly is heavily dependent on where you're defining it. If your variable is within the *root scope* of the CI/CD pipeline (I.e., either within a top-level `variable` block or within a `workflow` block) it **will work properly**. If you're attempting to define the rules within the scope of a job (I.e., within a `job:rules:if:variables` block), it **will not work properly**. Since your above example is within the workflow block, it will properly select your tag and apply it to downstream jobs.

You can see more information here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35742#note_704836498

Here is an example proving out the dynamic tag:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - variables:
        RUNNER: shared-macos-amd64

test:
  image: alpine:latest
  tags:
    - $RUNNER
  script:
    - echo $CI_RUNNER_DESCRIPTION
```

This properly picks up on the macos runner (and prints an error since I'm not in their beta):
[image: failed job]

Comment: Amazing this variable setting is working, you are right - but your example with the runner selection is not working for me. In the workflow section I have a rule which `if: '$TARGET == null && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature.*$/ || $TARGET == "dev"'` sets `variables:  RUNNER_ACCOUNT_SHELL: test-shell` but then in the job I get a "This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online or available with any of these tags assigned to them: $RUNNER_ACCOUNT_SHELL" error

Comment: That error usually means your variable isn't being set correctly, because the variable is interpreted as a string of it has no value. If you set a base value (with no if check), does it resolve that properly? If so, you'd need to check out your if check to ensure its working properly.

Comment: I “printed” the env variables in the first job and the parameter was assigned in the right way ... could it be a version problem?

Answer (score 0):

Updating on the answer of @Patrick I made it work and want to describe my solution. My problem was caused by the variables used—as I tested using a PR I never had `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` set, but using `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` it worked.

```
workflow:
  rules:
    # No build duplicates when committing to a branch with open pull request (PR)
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS"
      when: never
    # Deploy to development when PR from feature-branch
    - if: "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^feature.*$/"
      variables:
        TARGET: dev
    # Deploy to test when committing (after merging) to develop-branch
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
      variables:
        TARGET: test
    # Deploy to staging when committing (after merging) to release-branch
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^release\/.*$/'
      variables:
        TARGET: stage
    # Deploy to production when committing (after merging) to master-branch
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
      variables:
        TARGET: prod
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "parent_pipeline"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
```

The solution lays in the used [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

- CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME - The branch or tag name for which project is built.
- CI_COMMIT_BRANCH - The commit branch name. Available in branch pipelines, including pipelines for the default branch. Not available in merge request pipelines or tag pipelines.
- CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME - Unclear
- CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME -    The source branch name of the merge request.
- CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME - The target branch name of the merge request.
- CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS - A comma-separated list of up to four merge requests that use the current branch and project as the merge request source. Only available in branch and merge request pipelines if the branch has an associated merge request. For example, gitlab-org/gitlab!333,gitlab-org/gitlab-foss!11.